# Meaning of "sporting"

Tags: meaning, synonyms

In the phrase "On devices sporting the needed sensor, heart activity can be sampled," the word "sporting" obviously means "equipped." But in which cases the word "sporting" could substitute "equipped"?

Comment: heart activity can be sampled??Who wrote that? to sport something can mean to feature it. Probably a botched translation.

Answer (score 1):

When "sporting" is substituted for "equipped," I see it most often used in product advertisements or reviews. You might see something like "Renault's latest car model is sporting a heated steering wheel" as that would be an uncommon and notable feature. However, it would be highly unlikely that someone would write "Renault's latest car model is sporting a steering wheel" even though it's technically true.

Some examples:

- [Samsung's Galaxy A7](https://www.firstpost.com/tech/news-analysis/samsung-galaxy-a7-with-triple-camera-setup-launched-in-india-at-rs-23990-onwards-5255071.html), sporting a three camera setup at the
  back...
- [Kawasaki Ninja H2](https://gearpatrol.com/2013/08/27/50-most-iconic-motorcycles/), sporting a 998cc inline-four-cylinder and the
  first supercharger on a production motorcycle...
- [Raspberry Pi 4 vs Raspberry Pi 3](https://www.androidauthority.com/raspberry-pi-4-vs-raspberry-pi-3-model-b-1002489/), The new model sports four USB
  ports, with two of them sporting USB 3.0. This is a notable upgrade
  over the last model, which only featured four USB 2.0 ports.

In the case of a heartbeat sensor, that is still something that is uncommon on a phone, and not always present on a smart watch. It's much more common on a fitness watch but it's still feature you would have to specifically look for on any given model.

Answer (score 0):

I'm completely convinced that the word "sporting" is a typographical error, and it should be supporting

Comment: _Sporting_ can mean _wearing_ (some distinctive item of dress), so it could conceivably mean _displaying_ here, but it seems unlikely unless the rest of the passage is written in a semi-humorous style.

Comment: The text is contained on the Wikipedia page for Wear OS, which is an operating system for smart watches and other 'wearables'. I found a medical paper in Clinician Reviews entitled 'Sporting an Old Lesion'.